# Differentiate image errors and form errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). I have a form that submits both the inputs and the images when clicking the submit button. However, when I return an error that one of the inputs (NOT the image) was wrong, the `error` event will also show that the image has an error, even though it doesn't.

For example, if one of the inputs was empty and the form returned an error with the message "Please fill out the form", the uploaded image will (wrongly) also have an error and this changes in the HTML:

`<div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage="">[object Object]</span></div>`

The actual returned error (notice no error about the image):

`{"success":"false","messages":{"message":["The message field is required."]}}`

My question is, how can I modify my code to recognize whether or not the returned error is an error for the image or an error for the form inputs?

Here's my JS:

```
Dropzone.options.formPost = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 25,
    maxFiles: 25,
    maxFilesize: 5,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    clickable: "#image-upload",

    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;
        var form = $("#form-post");

        this.element.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener("click", function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });

        this.on("addedfile", function()
        {
            // some stuff
        });
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function()
        {
            // some stuff
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response)
        {
            // some stuff
        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response)
        {
            // if an error is return, even though it has nothing to do with the image, it will show that the image has an error
            $.each(response.messages, function(key, value)
            {
                form.find('.form-group#' + key).addClass('has-error');
                form.find('.form-group#' + key + ' .form-error').html(value[0]).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

PHP (Laravel):

```
public function createPost()
{
    $rules = array(
        'message' => 'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::except('file'), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => 'false',
            'messages' => $validator->messages()
        ), 400);
    }
    else
    {
        $post = new Post;
        $post->user_id = getUserID();
        $post->message = Input::get('message');
        $post->ip_address = getUserIP();
        $post->save();

        $files = Input::file('file');

        if ($files)
        {
            /**
             * Create a new directory for the post images.
             */
            File::makeDirectory(public_path() . '/uploads/posts/' . $post->id, 0775);

            foreach ($files as $file)
            {
                $file_rules = array('file' => 'image|max:5000');
                $validator = Validator::make(array('file' => $file), $file_rules);

                if ($validator->fails())
                {
                    return Response::json(array(
                        'success' => 'false',
                        'messages' => $validator->messages()
                    ), 400);
                }
                else
                {
                    $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $dest = public_path() . '/uploads/posts/' . $post->id . '/';
                    $file_name = str_random(6);

                    $upload_success = $file->move($dest, $file_name . '.' . $ext);

                    if (!$upload_success)
                    {
                        return Response::json(array(
                            'success' => 'false',
                        ), 400);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => 'true'
        ), 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the following code makes change to the image fields, when it is not supposed to do so.

```
form.find('.form-group#' + key).addClass('has-error');
form.find('.form-group#' + key + ' .form-error').html(value[0]).fadeIn();
```

You can do a manual check in your browser's JS console whether `form.find('.form-group#whatever')` is actually able to point to the correct element or not. Maybe `form.find('.form-group#whatever')` is pointing to all the input elements, which is causing problems.

It'll also be helpful to see the HTML code.